# CQLSSTableWriter USING TTL

Tags: cassandra-2.0, bulkloader

Can we use TTL on CQLSSTableWriter? like columnFamilyWriter.addExpiringColumn. (http://shareitexploreit.blogspot.in/2012/02/cassandra-bulk-loader.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can . Moreover , the CQLSSTableWriter you have been using is upgraded. Try using the latest one.

http://cassandrabee.blogspot.in/2014/04/cqlsstablewriter-bulk-loading-in.html

**How to use the TTL**

Just add the "`USING TTL ?`" to the insert query and bind the value to it.

Comment: Thanks Ananth, but I've check API(http://thydoc.com/cassandra/javadoc/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/CQLSSTableWriter.html), no TTL for CQLSSTableWriter.

Comment: You shall add using TTL to this statement 

-- INSERT INTO myKs.myTable (k, v1, v2) VALUES (?, ?, ?) USING TTL ? --

Post this , in addRow , the last argument will be the TTL value for this query.